# Работа с содержимым std::cin без предварительного извлечения содержимого в структуры программы

Tags: c++

Можно ли работать с содержимым стандартного cin "на месте" (допустим, необходима простая замена некоторого символа на другой) (предполагается затем вывести из std::cin в std::cout)?
Попытка использовать для этого функции unget(), putchar(char) не получилась.

Comment: Что означает на месте? Если Вы из cin считываете в какую-то переменную данные, почему Вы не можете в ней провести замену? Или Вы хотите менять поток ввода, чтобы при введении одного символа из буфера возвращался другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гарантируется возврат в поток только одного символа.

Поэтому "на месте" - нет, редактировать невозможно.

Но ведь вы все равно должны при переброске из `cin` в `cout` считывать в какие-то переменные вводимые данные? Вот там их и исправляйте. Особенно если нудно простое изменение символов - считали, изменили, вывели, пошли дальше.